# How To Extend mail.Chatter Widget in Javascript Odoo 10

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-10

I want to add a new event to "mail.Chatter" widget(mail/static/src/js/chatter.js) in Odoo 10.so I want to extend the "mail.Chatter" widget.

```
odoo.define('override_chatter.override_chatter', function (require) {
"use strict";

var Chatter = require('mail.Chatter');

console.log('Chatter', Chatter)



});
```

But from the console, I got some error. Please check below.

```
Chatter function Class(){if(this.constructor!==OdooClass){throw new Error("You can only instanciate objects with the 'new' operator");}
```

Please correct me if am wrong.Is there any other method to extend this "mail.Chatter" widget?

Comment: try Chatter.extend only. because Chatter returns only chatter object

Comment: @Burmesepythis console.log('Chatter', Chatter) . i getting an error while console the Chatter variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me

```
odoo.define('override_chatter.override_chatter', function (require) {
"use strict";

var core = require('web.core');
var Chatter = require('mail.Chatter');
var MailThread = core.form_widget_registry.get('mail_thread');

var MailThreadOverride = MailThread.include({

    init: function () {
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);

    },

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the file JS chatter.js you have 2 init function.

For ChatterComposer

```
init: function (parent, dataset, options) {
    this._super(parent, options);
    this.thread_dataset = dataset;
    this.suggested_partners = [];
    this.options = _.defaults(this.options, {
        display_mode: 'textarea',
        record_name: false,
        is_log: false,
    });
    if (this.options.is_log) {
        this.options.send_text = _t('Log');
    }
    this.events = _.extend(this.events, {
        'click .o_composer_button_full_composer': 'on_open_full_composer',
    });
},
```

And for Chatter

```
init: function () {
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    this.model = this.view.dataset.model;
    this.res_id = undefined;
    this.context = this.options.context || {};
    this.dp = new web_utils.DropPrevious();
},
```

And if I seeing your code. You try to overwrite the init of Chatter whit the init params of ChatterComposer .

Comment: var Chatter = require('mail.Chatter');
console.log('Chatter', Chatter) 

                                                                                                                     i console the "Chatter". here i getting this error "Chatter function Class(){if(this.constructor!==OdooClass){throw new Error("You can only instanciate objects with the 'new' operator");}" 

its nothing to do with "init" function.i think. @jo541

Comment: This message is normally. Your try to calling the not initialized Class.

Comment: var Chatter = require('mail.Chatter'); console.log('Chatter', Chatter.Chatter). Getting "undefined" in console. seems like Chatter can't be extended ??

Comment: Chatter can be extended because at the end of the file chatter.js you can seeing "return Chatter".

Comment: Hello @robinjoseph90, are you getting any answer ? because,  I have same problem and don't have any clue to resolve this problem. If you have solution so please post here.

Comment: @Debasish Please check below answer.